# Single User Single Login

Tags: c#

I've Created one Desktop Application which has server client access... Every user will has different login. Now the problem is, when one user is login, the same user cannot be login from other pc... The msg should come as the 'user is already Login'. In ASP.Net, it can be achieved through session.. But, how can I do this in Desktop Application. There is one solution.. We can maintain one log table for the logined users. But, that too will face deadlock situation.... Is any other solution for the single user login??

Comment: Just want to add an small comment. 'User is already in use' is not a good answer to stop attempts then user is already logged in, because it "can" be brute forced to get usernames. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: Of course you should not display the "already logged in" message unless the correct credentials are entered (username AND password not just username). Then there is no more information leakage then usual.

Comment: Ok.. That's not a problem.. But, I should not allow to login further, if the user is already logged in a different pc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a timeout of the login to avoid deadlock and also send "live" signals to the server to update the status that the user is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to check whether your user is logged in or not, before the login itself. You can use a special field in the User table or in a special table for that. What deadlocks? All you need is a read access to make sure particular user was not logged in.

Comment: What I suspect he means with a deadlock is for those situations where a user doesn't log out (Application crash, network problems etc.). If that isn't handled, the user will have problems logging in again.

Comment: That could be mitigated with an "activity timeout" - i.e. if the user hasn't accessed the application in x minutes / seconds / hours (depending on the app and how often it is used) then they are automatically kicked.  It's a bit of a kludge, but it would work in some situations.

Comment: How should I know that he didn't accessed the application??

Comment: On every operation you can be sure he is accessing it and write access time. So when you need to check how many time he didn`t access the application - check that time. Sure you can treat other user activity as accessing your forms\controls and make your app live longer. So it can be done in such a way: if no activity for a long time - logout current user.